# $ is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I keep getting the error message `Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` while wanting to use a list of artist names to consult an API. The strange thing is though, sometimes it does work (mostly first time only) and then it starts showing the error code when trying to use the same code with a different/adjusted list.

```
################################################################################
########## This code gives you the related artists from Spotify's API ##########
################################################################################

###############################
####### needed packages #######
###############################
library(Rspotify)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

###############################
####### Spotify API key #######
###############################

keys <- spotifyOAuth("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx")

###################################
## Create a vector of artistnames##
###################################
names_artists <- artist_names$artist_name
names_artists

################################################################

# Create empty list
datalist = list()

## Tell loop to iterate over all entries p in track_id ##
## might need to split list into two or more ##

for(p in names_artists) {
  pl <- getRelated(p ,token=keys) %>%   # Call the function and iteration p and put it into dataframe pl
    mutate(artist_name = p)    # Use Dplyrs mutate-function to add a column with the artist name in iteration
  datalist[[p]] <- pl   # Add artist name to datalist
}
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The `$` operator only works with recursirve objects (list, dataframes that are build from list..), are u sure that  `artists2` always gave you a dataframe? your error is because the `$` is applied to a 1-D vector (check before with `str()` and `is.atomic()`)

Comment: It's indeed not recursive but for some reason this code did use to work, and occasionally sometimes does (.... I know it's strange). If I make the object recursive (a.g. list) the function stops working and shows ``Error in is.url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE}`` - if you have a solution for this I would be happy too ;-)

Comment: What is the type and output of `artist_names`? From the variable name, it doesn't seem like it would be a 2D vector

Comment: The artist_names object's type is a list.